# Scraping the moves of Lichess

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to create a suggestion AI about a best move in chess.
I don't really get the HTML tag of lichess in bs4.

In Chrome I can actually see the tag in bs4 it is an script based command.
I will show some code for a better understanding.

That's my script for scraping the data.

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
from time import time


def scrape_data_from_lichess(url):
    response = get(url)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    move_played = html_soup.find_all('move')
    print(move_played)

while not scrapeData:
    scrape_data_from_lichess(webpage + url)
    time.sleep(10)
```

That is my Google Devtool respond of the location of the tag.
It is really odd because the Chrome Extension 'Web Scraper' can actually detect these tags.

```html
<div class="moves">
  <index class="">1</index>
  <move class="">d4</move>
  <move class="">d6</move>
  <index class="">2</index>
  <move class="active">Nf3</move>
  <move class="">Nf6</move>
</div>
```

And the last one is my bs4 result of the html text. It is the short version. I modified it.

```python
LichessRound.boot({
    data: {"game":{"player":"white","opponent":{"color":"black","name":null,"ai":1},"san":"d4","san":"d6","san":"Nf3",{"san":"Nf6"}]},
```

Here is the long version.

```python
LichessRound.boot({
data: {"game":{"id":"4PAVr8QI","variant":{"key":"standard","name":"Standard","short":"Std"},"speed":"correspondence","perf":"correspondence","rated":false,"initialFen":"rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1","fen":"rnbqkb1r/ppp1pppp/3p1n2/8/3P4/5N2/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 2 3","player":"white","turns":4,"startedAtTurn":0,"source":"ai","status":{"id":20,"name":"started"},"createdAt":1536082009777,"lastMove":"g8f6","opening":{"eco":"A46","name":"Indian Game: Wade-Tartakower Defense","ply":4}},"clock":null,"correspondence":null,"player":{"color":"white","name":null,"user":{"id":"gamelinetv","username":"Gamelinetv","online":true,"perfs":{"correspondence":{"games":0,"rating":1500,"rd":350,"prog":0,"prov":true}}},"rating":1500,"provisional":true,"version":4,"spectator":true},"opponent":{"color":"black","name":null,"ai":1},"orientation":"white","url":{"socket":"/4PAVr8QI/white/socket","round":"/4PAVr8QI/white"},"pref":{"animationDuration":300,"coords":2,"replay":2,"clockTenths":1,"clockBar":true,"highlight":true,"destination":true,"rookCastle":true,"showCaptured":true},"evalPut":false,"steps":[{"ply":0,"uci":null,"san":null,"fen":"rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"},{"ply":1,"uci":"d2d4","san":"d4","fen":"rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/3P4/8/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 1"},{"ply":2,"uci":"d7d6","san":"d6","fen":"rnbqkbnr/ppp1pppp/3p4/8/3P4/8/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 2"},{"ply":3,"uci":"g1f3","san":"Nf3","fen":"rnbqkbnr/ppp1pppp/3p4/8/3P4/5N2/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKB1R b KQkq - 1 2"},{"ply":4,"uci":"g8f6","san":"Nf6","fen":"rnbqkb1r/ppp1pppp/3p1n2/8/3P4/5N2/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 2 3"}]},
```

I know that Selenium can fix the problem. But it start a new Browser and I just want to paste the script and get the data of the moves. So I decided to use BS4, but I am open for new ideas.

Comment: I suppose that the moves get updated dynamically, probably using javascript. That's probably the reason why you see the moves using your browser but the script can't see them. Take a look at [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which can simulate a browser and is fully compatible with [`bs4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the API https://lichess.org/api?

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on the great [suggestion from Wolfgang Fahl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52172376/scraping-the-moves-of-lichess-in-bs4/74983568#comment105054600_52172376) to use [Lichess API](https://lichess.org/api). Either use one of the Python APIs recommended there or ..

#### Use [`python-lichess`](https://pypi.org/project/python-lichess/)

Install using `pip install python-lichess`, then get the moves of given [`game`](https://python-lichess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=moves#lichess.api.game):

```py
import lichess.api

game = lichess.api.game('4PAVr8QI')
print(game['moves'])
```

Prints:

```
d4 d6 Nf3 Nf6
```