# Get last line segment from string

Tags: python

I have a string and I need to get a certain segment from the end (from the beginning to *)

```
Stockfish level 5 - Anon. • lichess.orgAccessibility: Enable blind mode


lichess.orgPlaylichess.orgCreate a gameArena tournamentsSwiss tournamentsSimultaneous exhibitionsPuzzlesPuzzlesPuzzle DashboardPuzzle StreakPuzzle StormPuzzle RacerLearnChess basicsPracticeCoordinatesStudyCoachesWatchLichess TVCurrent gamesStreamersBroadcastsVideo libraryCommunityPlayersTeamsForumBlogToolsAnalysis boardOpening explorerBoard editorImport gameAdvanced search

Sign in∞ • Casual • Correspondence 20 minutes agoStockfish level 5AnonymousCorrespondence Chess • Stockfish level 5 vs Anon.Stockfish level 5 plays Anon. in a casual Correspondence game of chess. Game is still being played after 1 moves. Click to replay, analyse, and discuss the game![Event "Casual Correspondence game"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/dtkxPuQf"]
[Date "2023.01.02"]
[White "lichess AI level 5"]
[Black "Anonymous"]
[Result "*"]
[UTCDate "2023.01.02"]
[UTCTime "12:43:13"]
[WhiteElo "?"]
[BlackElo "?"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[TimeControl "-"]
[ECO "B00"]
[Opening "King's Pawn"]
[Termination "Unterminated"]

1. e4 *Reconnecting
```

Output: 1. e4

I tried `text[text.find('1. '):].partition("*")[0]` But sometimes it outputs "]" instead of the desired value

I need to get moves from the game in time sense and notify me of new moves

Comment: Well, you will have to figure out the exact problem setting. E.g. the first `1. ` in the text may happen before the first asterisk. `I need to get a certain segment from the end (from the beginning to \*)` is accomplished by just `text.split('\*')[0]`. You have to have more examples where your approach works and where it doesn't - odds are though, you'd figure it out on your own by then. I would recommend just skipping the header lines first, their number should be consistent in your use case.

Comment: You can also use Python regex module's [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to find the first move. `import re; re.findall(r'1. [a-h][1-8]', text)` returns a list with one element `['1. e4']`.

Comment: Please [edit] your questions and provide more context. E.g. What textual information are you trying to get from this web-site? E.g. "I want to get all the moves from a Lichess game specified by given ID like https://lichess.org/dtkxPuQf". Then we could also suggest to use suitable Python libraries.

Comment: @hc_dev, 
I need to get moves from the game in time sense and notify me of new moves

Answer (score 1):

Instead of retrieving the HTML of a **specific game** from the **Lichess** web-page (https://lichess.org/dtkxPuQf) and then parsing the text-representation to extract the **moves** it would be easier to use an Lichess API-wrapper for that.

Compare both solutions below.

### Parse the web-page as text-content

Using `requests` and `bs4` like in your previous question/answer:

- [Increment of the detect line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74981773/increment-of-the-detect-line/74982111#74982111)

Your answered attempt there was:

```py
while True:
    r = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE)
    soup = bs(r.text, "lxml")

    main_buffer = soup.text[soup.text.find('1. '):].partition("*")[0]

    while True:
        buffer = bs(requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE).text, 'lxml').text[soup.text.find('1. '):].partition("*")[0]  # issue here
        if len(main_buffer) < len(buffer):
            main_buffer = buffer
            break

    print(main_buffer)
```

Now you have an issue with `text[soup.text.find('1. '):].partition("*")[0]`.

### Use a wrapper for Lichess API

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74983568/5730279) to similar question:

Install the wrapper using `pip install python-lichess`, then get the [moves of given `game`](https://python-lichess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=moves#lichess.api.game) specified by game-ID `'dtkxPuQf'`:

```
import lichess.api

game = lichess.api.game('dtkxPuQf')
print(game)  # test update by 'lastMoveAt': 1672665999834, 'status': 'started'

print(game['moves'])  # moves as list of str in PGN-notation, order as played
```

Prints:

```
e4 d6 d4 e6 Bd3 h5 Nf3 g5 Bxg5 f5
```

The first move is the first element `game['moves'].split()[0]` (here `e4`), the last played move is `game['moves'].split()[-1]` (here `f5`).

#### Polling for updates

A loop could poll the API's game-resource and compare agains the saved `game` object (dict).
To detect if an update happened in the meantime, we simply could check the 3 items:

1. `game['lastMoveAt']`: if the timestamp was not changed, then are up-to-date.
2. `game['status']`: if someone resigns then it would have changed - without any further move happening.
3. `game['moves']`: the difference here are the moves appended in the meantime.

So, we need 2 variables to compare game-states: `lastSnapshot` and `currentSnapshot`.

**Warning:** Be aware of [Lichess API's Rate Limiting](https://lichess.org/api#section/Introduction/Rate-limiting):

> All requests are rate limited using various strategies, to ensure the API remains responsive for everyone. Only make one request at a time. If you receive an HTTP response with a 429 status, please wait a full minute before resuming API usage.

So you should use a appropriate poll-interval to have long-enough delays between your requests.

#### See also

- Wikipedia: [Portable Game Notation (PGN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation)